# What is wrong with my use of setSelectionRange?

Tags: javascript, html

The text in the `div` is not getting selected. What am I doing wrong?

To test, double-click the `div`, type some text, then click away. 
[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXjGOX).

```
<script>
  function editIt(div){
    // console.log(div.textContent);  
    div.contentEditable=true
    div.focus()
  }

  function selectIt(div){
    // div.focus
    div.setSelectionRange(2, 2)
    div.focus()
  }
</script>

  <div ondblclick="editIt(this)" style="border:1px solid; width:100px; height:20px" onblur="selectIt(this)" />
```

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setSelectionRange` only works on `input` elements, and you seem to be working with a `div`.  Check the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)**

Also see the **[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdWdbj)** when I replaced it with an input element.

Comment: This does answer the question, "What's wrong with my use of setSelectionRange. But i'm not trying to select the contents of an `input`, i'm trying to select the contents of a content-editable `div`. I've learned the proper solution is `collapse`.

Comment: `collapse` for non-ie, and createRange for ie. Full solution here https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/set-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div/6574/4.

Comment: My title is misleading, but I think it's clear from the content of the question that what i'm really trying to do is select text in a content-editable div, which you did not answer.